# Rewrite URL with parameters passed through PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

So I have my PHP page page.php with the parameter id for example.

Everything works as expected when I visit

```
page.php?id=1
```

What I try to do now basically is, reach the site when the user visits

```
page/1
```

I've looked at countless questions and websites about htaccess rewrites and so on, but I'm not even entirely sure if I need that. I did the exact same thing in an old project of mine where I can't find any htaccess file, but I also have no idea what I really did.

And in case I do need the htaccess file. How do I ensure that it works properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, gotta put this in the htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ /page.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```